# Как правильно использовать Retrofit library?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Мне необходимо спроектировать Rest Api приложение.
В интернете, в том числе в официальной документации показаны примеры использования данной библиотеки выполняя запросы напрямую из Activity, но это ведь неправильно?!
Сетевые запросы нужно выполнять с помощью Service?!
Как правильно это сделать c помощью Retrofit? Не хочу выдумывать свой "Велосипед".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В официальной документации делается акцент на то, чтобы показать как использовать данную библиотеку, а не на то как лучше спроектировать приложение.

Я, например, использую связку [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)+[rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)+[eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) и работаю по следующей схеме: методы ретрофита возвращают `Observable<T>` вокруг которого я начинаю "накручивать" логику(запрос к серверу в отдельном потоке,обработчик ошибок, действия над результатом, обработчик успешного результата). В конце отправляю событие с флагом успешно ли прошел запрос или произошла какая либо ошибка. В итоге код выглядит следующим образом

```
public class RestInteractionWorker {

    RestServerInterface restInterface;

    public RestInteractionWorker(){
        //создаем объект RestServerInterface
    }

    public void perfomServerOperation(){
        restInterface.perfomOperation(...)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //для запроса используем отдельный поток
                .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // таймаут 
                .map(new Func1<T, ActionEvent>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ActionEvent call(T someModel) {

                        // обрабатываем результат, после чего высылаем событие с флагом успешного выполнения запроса                        
                        return event;
                    }
                })
                .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, TownsTemperatureUpdateEvent>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ActionEvent call(Throwable throwable) {
                        // произошла ошибка, создаем событие сообщающее об ошибке
                        return new TownsTemperatureUpdateEvent(false);
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // дальше код будет вызываться в главном потоке приложения
                .subscribe(new Action1<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(ActionEvent event) {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(event); // высылаем событие 
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Интерфейс запросов к серверу выглядит так:

```
public interface RestServerInterface {

    @GET("/...")
    Observable<T> perfomOperation(...);
}
```

Вместо `T` надо указать конкретный тип, который будет возвращен.

Данную модель я использую когда надо получить данные сервера и сохранить их в базу данных, после чего в приложении отобразить новые обновленные данные. В методе `map(...)` я сохраняю данные в бд, и возвращаю из него `event` с флагом успешной загрузки и сохранения данных, после чего в методе `subscribe(...)` высылаю это событие. В дальнейшем это событие перехватывает тот кто на него подписан и обновляет данные.

Метод `onErrorReturn(...)` перехватывает все исключения которые произошли во время выполнения.

Если не нужно сохранять данные в бд, а, например, сразу выслать модельный объект, то метод `map(...)` можно не реализовывать.

Классы событий выглядят примерно следующим образом:

```
public class ActionEvent {

    private final boolean isSuccessefull;
    private final String message;
    //можно передавать дополнительную информацию

    public ActionEvent(boolean isSuccessefull, String message) {
        this.isSuccessefull = isSuccessefull;
        this.message = message;

    public boolean isSUccessefull() {
        return isSUccessefull;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

В активити/фрагменте обрабатываю события так:

```
public void onEvent(ActionEvent event) {

    //обработка результата

}

public void onResume(){    
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this); // подписываемся на прием событий
    super.onResume();
}

public void onPause(){
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this); // отписываемся от получения событий
    super.onPause();
}
```

Новичку данная модель может показаться сложноватой из-за использования библиотеки `rxJava`, но в целом для меня это довольно успешная модель реализации взаимодействия приложения с сервером.

`Refrofit` можно так же использовать в связке с [Robospise](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). В ней как раз все запросы выполняются через `Service`. Пример можно найти в их репозиторие.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ :)

Comment: Разобрался) Все хорошо)
Но есть пару вопросов:
1) Безопасен ли такой подход если активити вдруг неожиданно будет остановлена системой, запрос выполнится до конца?
2) В идеале для каждого Retroft интерфейса нужно создавать отдельный RestInteractionWorker? Или можно все запросы в одном месте собрать?
3) Возможно ли остановить принудительно выполняемый http запрос с помощью данного подхода?

Comment: @user3910670 1) Да, запрос выполнится до конца.
2) Я обычно логически разбиваю запросы на подгруппы(например операции с заказами, с профилем) и для каждой подгруппы создаю интерфейс с набором всех методов для нее и свой класс который дергает методы из этого набора.
3) В данной ситуации остановить запрос на середине не получится.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз) Мне очень нравится ход ваших мыслей и организация модели)