# PHP сервер для Android приложения

Tags: php, android, клиент-сервер

Как с php сервере получить запрос с android клиента и отправить ответ. 
Пробую просто надпись вернуть с помощью HttpUrlConnection, но возвращается Unexpected status line: J������

Самое простое что пробовал

```
<?php
    echo "<h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>";
?>


URL myUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3306/chatserver/");
HttpURLConnection con;

con = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                con.connect();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));

String str = "";
while((str = reader.readLine())!=null)
{
   Log.d("+++++++++++++++++++", "RESPONSE: "  + str);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки Retrofit 2. В сети есть много примеров работы с ней. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494099/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-retrofit https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443790/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-retrofit-library Если возникают какие-то проблемы, опишите задачу более конкретно.

Comment: С помощью `HttpUrlConnection` из пакета `java.net` можно работать с `get/post` запросами и в Android. Другое дело, для того чтобы понять в чём ошибка очень мало сведений. Приведите пожалуйста [минимальный самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Иначе от вопроса не будет никакого толку ни для Вас, ни для других.

Comment: А открывается ли у вас "http://10.0.2.2:3306/chatserver/"?

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае нужно воспользоваться примером: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/579712/284397

замените строчку кода на свою:

`String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3306/chatserver/";`

Comment: Ссылка на источник ответа - это хорошо, но описать все же нужно подробно.